# Simple Question : about python class parenthesis

Tags: python, python-3.x

Look at the code below.

```
class A :
  def __init__(self, a = "Hello") :
    self.a = a

print(A().a) # 1

print(A.a) # 2
```

1 is not error

2 is error - AttributeError: type object 'A' has no attribute 'a'

What is the difference between the two results?

Comment: `A()` creates an *instance* of the class, which *does* have an `a` attribute. `A` is just the class itself, which doesn't.

Comment: With parenthesis you instanciate the class A so you get an instance who have the 'a' attribute. 2: class A has no attribute a itself

Comment: But there could be methods you can cal directly from class, called classmethods. Nice explanation about topic: https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/classmethod

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code `A` refers the the type of a class and also to its constructor/initialiser. `A` is called the **class** and when you construct an object of type `A` with the constructor you get an **instance** of that class.

```
A  # Refers to the class A
A()  # is an instance of class A
```

There is a difference between a class property and an instance property. Consider the following code:

```
class A:
  propertyA = "hello"

  def __init__(self, string="world"):
    self.propertyB = string
```

In this snippet `propertyA` is a class property while `propertyB` is an instance property. Each instance of type A has its own `propertyB` and you must instantiate and object (an instance) first.

```
A.propertyA  # Class property, does not need an instance
A().propertyB  # instance property, needs an instance
```

In your code the constructor for A is the code written in the `__init__`. This code will be called when you type `A()`. Note that you specified a default value for the parameter `a` but if you don't you would call the constructor like this:

```
A("hello")  # or:
A(a="hello")
```

Note that classes, instances and constructors are fundamentals of OOP (and by extension Python), you really should learn this, it avoids lots of basic errors.

Comment: Thank you so much. I was definitely understand to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an instance of the class first:

```
class A :
    def __init__(self, a = "Hello") :
        self.a = a

class_instance = A()
print(class_instance.a)
```

You can set the value of "a" when creating the instance by typing in the parenthesis:

```
class_instance = A("this is the value of a")
```

you can change the value after the creation like so:

```
class_instance.a = "New value of a"
```

A().a is creating an instance and returns the a value of the instance.
A.a cannot be executed because A is the Class name and doesn't have any attributes if you don't create an instance first